# Flutter Firebase Error signin using google

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

i got an error when i press the login with google button , 
Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 7: , null))

i already try this step >https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent

and also already try to change my gradle and etc

this is my auth.dart code

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class AuthService {
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;
  Observable<FirebaseUser> user; // firebase user
  Observable<Map<String, dynamic>> profile; // custom user data in Firestore
  AuthService() {
    user = Observable(_auth.onAuthStateChanged);

    profile = user.switchMap((FirebaseUser u) {
      if (u != null) {
        return _db
            .collection('users')
            .document(u.uid)
            .snapshots()
            .map((snap) => snap.data);
      } else {
        return Observable.just({});
      }
    });
  }

  Future<FirebaseUser> googleSignIn() async {

    GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;


    print("signed in " + user.displayName);
    return user;
  }


  void signOut() {
    _auth.signOut();
  }
}

final AuthService authService = AuthService();
```

and this is my sign in button code

```
Widget button() {
    return RaisedButton(
      elevation: 0,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
      onPressed: () => authService.googleSignIn().whenComplete(() {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(HOME_PAGE);
      }),
      textColor: Colors.white,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        width: _large ? _width / 4 : (_medium ? _width / 3.75 : _width / 3.5),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: <Color>[Colors.orange[200], Colors.pinkAccent],
          ),
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: Text('SIGN IN',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: _large ? 14 : (_medium ? 12 : 10))),
      ),
    );
  }
```

i expect after login i can go to HOME_PAGE but it return error message,

Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 7: , null))

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually comes when the device has ***network connectivity issue***.

- **Happy Learning!**